# bulkCreate records using sequelize in nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Any way to do a bulk update, create using sequelize and postgres?

I have tried the following:

```
   sequelize.models.Location.bulkCreate(updatedPost.locations,
 { ignoreDuplicates: true }).then(function (locations) {
                            res.send(updatedPost);
                            res.end();
                        });
```

I got this error:

> postgres does not support the 'ignoreDuplicates' option.

Comment: Avoid passing `ignoreDuplicates` :). The sql syntax required for this is not supported by postgres. You can use `updateOnDuplicate` instead, if you want to update any existing rows - otherwise you will have to live with an error if there are duplicates

Comment: `updateOnDuplicate` is [also not supported](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/69c8dc40086b6a099c31c2b5ed37ad28610affca/lib/model.js#L1976) Unfortunately you can't bulk-create with sequelize:postgres if there's a chance of errors. `.then()` won't be reached (instead `.catch()` or `.finally()`) and you therefore can't continue your query promise chain. I presume any inserts after the failed will stop.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING/UPDATE is a thing on Postgres now. They have [really good documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html). So you could do Sequelize.query() to do it.
But I'm sorry Sequelize still does not support it natively. You have to write a method on your model to do it.